# Memory Utilisation above 4 GB on 32 bit m/c

Tags: windows, sql-server

We have database server with 16 GB RAM.SQL server installation is 32 bit.There are 3 instances of SQL server on the Database Server.AWE is on.

Memory is allocated as follows

```
    Instance 1 -6 GB
    Instance 2 -5 GB
    Instance 3 -3 GB
```

As we know memory above 4 GB is accessed throuth AWE,that means it is not native.So it can be used only for buffer cache and not procedure cache.So how much of native memory is allocated to each instance?Is it also proportional to memory allocation or one instance may get all native memory and others are only on Extended memory?

Comment: is the /3GB switch in use? if not then you only have 2GB of memory for application?

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely possible that one instance will have the bulk of the space that can be used for procedure cache.  32bit SQL can use only 1 Gig of execution cache per instance.  If other apps are taking a lot of the native memory, and there's less than 3 Gigs of native memory, then the SQL instances could end up battling for the resources.

Answer (score 0):

I would really look into a 64bit OS with that much RAM. You're chasing your tail otherwise.